# add columns based on repetions and conditions of other columns R

Tags: r

I'm a bit lost about the best way to perform what I want in R.

I have a dataframe with several columns. One of them is user and other column, let's say number (0,1,2,3,4,5). Sometimes the user is repeated but the column number should have a sequence of numbers in this case. Can be something like this:

```
user number  column B column C
1    0        85      200
2    1        165     852
1    2        200     1000
3    0        15      689
3    1        89      896
4    0        78      582
4    2        96      586
```

What I would like to obtain is:

```
user number status days
1    0      0       200
3    0      1       50 ->(value column C, user 3, number 1)-(value column B, user 3, number 0)
4    0      0       200
```

I want to add two columns to the dataframe based on values from these users.

- If user has a number == 0 but user is unique status == 0 and days == some predefined number
- If user has a number == 0 and the user is not unique

  - If second appearance of user has a number == 1, status == 1 and days should be a subtraction from a value column C second appearance of user - value column B first appearance of user
  - If second appearance of user has a number != 1, status == 0 and days == some predefined number
- Remove from dataset users that don't have number == 0

I'm asking this question because I'm a bit confused about the best way to do this. I though about subset the dataframe where number == 0 and then compare users between dataframes to see repeated users but perhaps is it not the best way to do this.

Any pointers and ideas would be great!

Thank you for your help

**EDIT**

columnB is the number of days that have passed since '2002-01-01'. For instance the first user enter in the dataframe 85 days after 2002-01-01

columnC is the number of days that the user stayed in observation. After those days the user is no longer in the database.

**EDIT2**

My dataset has 36 columns and 26075rows

After some suggestions where's what I have so far.

```
#remove from dataset all users that don't have number == 0
df1 <- df[df$user %in% df[df$number == 0,1],]

df1["Status"] <- 0

#doesn't work
df1[df1$number == 1 %in% df1[duplicated(df1$user),]]
```

What I was trying to do is to find all duplicated users and if the number is equal to 1. To try something like this afterwards:

```
 df1[df1$number == 1 %in% df1[duplicated(df1$user),]] <- df1$Status == 1
```

Comment: where did `days` come from?  .."some predefined number" doesn't help us help you..  and are your data always sorted by user and number ascending?  :)

Comment: you could write up a function that does what you want for one user and then use ddply to run this function over all users.

Comment: I don't know others but I find it difficult to understand from your example and description what you really want. For example what are column "C" or "B"?

Comment: sorry @Anthony Damico, the predefined number of days is not always the same actually. It should be the days between '2009-12-31' and the date of other column.

Comment: @EDi your idea is actually good. I'll try to do something like that :)

Comment: @ValentinRuano I hope my edit helps to understand a bit better. basically it is a dataframe of patients in observation. and these columns refers to different times in their observations. but they are in days, so it is a number

Comment: I'd start with your last condition, removing all rows with `user` values that never have `number==0`.  That gives you a smaller dataset to have to crunch with the rest of your conditions.  Here's how to do that:  `foo[foo[,1]%in%foo[foo[,2]==0,1],]`

Comment: check out the docs for the "duplicated" method as it may weel help. More concretely duplicated(data$user) will give you a logical vector with trues for user ids already seen

Comment: @ValentinRuano I'm aware of that however I'm not sure how to use this logical vector to compare with others columns and replace values..

Comment: @pavid I guess you can get those user id that have duplicated... Can you tell use about the data volume? how many user does your data have, how many rows? how many rows per user (only up to two rows)? If is not to big there is no need to thing to hard in an efficient solution.

Comment: @ValentinRuano see my edit. I've also updated some code that I'm trying to play around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #order the dataset by columns needed
 df2 <- df2[order(df2$user, df2$number),]

 ids <- unique(df2$user)

 #create variable status and days
 status <- NULL
 end <- NULL
 for (i in 1:length(ids)) {
     aux <- df2[df2$user %in% ids[i],]
     if (nrow(aux) == 1 & aux$number[1] == 0){
          status[i] <- 0
          days[i] <- end
     } else if (nrow(aux) > 1) {
          status[i] <- 1
          days[i] <- aux$Event[2]
     } else {
          status[i] <- NA
          days[i] <- NA
     }
 }

 #merge the vector created with the database
 data <- data.frame(ids, status, days)
 df2 <- df2[!duplicated(df2$user),]
 df2 <- merge(df2, data, by.x="user", by.y="ids")

 #remove NAs from the dataset
 df.f <- df2[!(is.na(df2$days)),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps subseting a data.frame per each user is not the most efficient way but it might be good enough for your data volume if you don't need an answer in just a few seconds.

```
ids = unique(df1$user);
status.days = sapply(ids,function(id) {
   udf = subset(df1,subset= user == id);
   if (nrow(udf) == 1) {
     status = 0;
     days = XXX; # the predefined value.
   } else if (udf$number[2] != 1) {
     status = 0;
     days = XXX; # the predefined value;
   } else {
     status = 1;
     days = udf$columnC[2] - udf$columnB[1];
   }
   c(status,days)
});

status = sapply(status.days,simplify=T,function(sd) { sd[1] });
days = sapply(status.days,simplify=T,function(sd) { sd[2] });

result = data.frame(user=ids,number=rep(0,length(ids)),status=status,days=days)
```

I have to confess that I am not sure about the indexing to extract status and days from the temporal list "status.days"... perhaps instead of sd[1] and sd[2] it should be sd[1][1] , sd[1][2] or sd[[1]][1], sd[[1]][2]

Comment: So to do something like this: df1[df1$number == 1 %in% df1[duplicated(df1$user),]] (but working :p) is not possible?

Comment: To be honest I don't know what that expression is going to produce. Looking at your last edit I guess what you want is simply unique(df1$user[df1$number == 1]) to ge the ids of those users. Or perhaps you want their number == 1 records? In that case df1[df1$number == 1]. Isn't it guaranteed that if number == 1 the user is duplicated already (i.e has more than on row with its id)?

Comment: In any case the solution I provide tries to solve the initial problem now that I think I understand it, without looking to previous discussions on solutions. The potential problem with this solution is that it might not be the most efficient one but I reckon that it should be good enough for your data volume.

Comment: I was thinking something more along those lines unique(df1$user[df1$number == 1]) but I'll try our solution. Thank you!

Comment: just be careful with some details that I have not tested such the indexing to extract status and days in the second and third apply. Also the simplify=T option, as far as I remember that is the syntax to force sapply to return and array instead of a list but needs checking. And of course $columnB might need to be changed depending on the actual name of that column. Let me suggest that you change those names in the input data frame to something more informative and convenient progamatically (i.e. without blanks)

Comment: although I don't want to create a new dataframe because I want to keep the remaining columns.perhaps a match or merge would work.

Comment: With what objective? Save memory? Since you are going to remove some rows in the final data-frame (those with number != 0) I don't see how are you going to be able to reuse any column vector value. By the way did the solution work? if any modification was needed, a part from coding style, please edit the solution.

Comment: Well I want to model only those that have number 0, so everything is fine anyway. This is just for manipulation purpose, at the end I'm going to build a model with the data that I want. I wasn't able to work with your solution, I trying to adapt it..

Comment: I used your example and sightly modified it. I will post it as an answer for anyone interested. Thank you very much